# How do I retrieve message and reaction info from reaction add payload?

Tags: python, discord, bots, message

I'm writing a discord bot in python and I'd like to have the bot do some actions after specific user reactions on messages. I need the message.content.

I am able to get the payload which can give me a message_id, user_id, channel_id etc. For some reason I'm stuck with the ID's and dont seem to understand how to get a message from the message_id. I have tried every variation of fetch_message() under the sun and cant get it to work.

I've tried discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message, payload.fetch_message, Client.fetch_message, discord.fetch_message. I have no idea how this works and the documentation gives nothing[text](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message%20id#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message)

The errors are all some variation of:
AttributeError: type object 'Client' has no attribute 'fetch_message'

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  channel = payload.channel_id
  messageID = payload.message_id
  msg = discord.Client.fetch_message(messageID)
```